# Flutter print() and delayed function not running

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to delay navigating to another screen but neither the delay function is working nor the print statements are showing in the console. Recently I have upgraded flutter. I don't know if that's causing it. Even debugging doesn't work correctly. Sometimes going back and forth delay works. Sometimes it doesn't.

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: containerHeight * 0.08, top: 10),
      child: _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : RaisedButton(
      color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: ()
                async {
                 if(_formkey.currentState.validate())
                  {
                   print('Login Form Vaildated');
                   setState(() {
                   _isLoading = true;
                   });

                   try {
                     print('Going to login');
                      await Utils.login(usernameController.text, passController.text);
                      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7)).then((_){
                      print('Inside Delayed');
                      Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                                                          return DataEntryScreen(userName:Utils.email,);
                                                        }));

                       setState(() {
                       _isLoading = false;
                       });
                      });
                      } on HttpException catch(error){
                            print('Inside HTTP Exp');
                            var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed';
                            if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
                              errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use.';
                             } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
                               errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address';
                             } else if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
                               errorMessage = 'This password is too weak.';
                             } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
                               errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email.';
                             } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
                               errorMessage = 'Invalid password.';
                             }
                             setState(() {
                              _isLoading = false;
                             });
                              _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
                              print(errorMessage);
                              } catch(error){
                                 const errorMessage ='Could not authenticate you. Please try again later.';
                                 _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
                                  setState(() {
                                       _isLoading = false;
                                      });

                                       }
                                     }
                                 },
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign in',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
```

Comment: share us the result from the flutter doctor please

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Android studio wasn't applying the changes I was making and saving.
So this is what I did.

- Upgraded pub packages because I upgraded flutter before and didn't
  upgrade the packages.
- Created a new project and copied all the dart    files in lib from
  old project to new project.
- Also installed a new emulator device incase some old data in old
  emulator was causing the issue.

Everything works fine now.